# How can I make my scss to update css file faster on a network server?

Tags: css, sass, server

I'm developing a WordPress site on network web server. I have mapped the web server on my local computer and now it acts like it's on my local.

I'm using Bones as my theme and it uses SCSS. So I cd to my mapped server which is Z: and go the the theme library and typed compass watch.

It's updating the css with no problem but it's very slow. It's not real time. I need to wait for at least 2min for the css to be updated.

Is there any way I can make the update faster? Or is there any other way to this? I'm not sure if I'm doing it right in the first place.

I'm using compass watch to update my css file via cmd on windows network server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any way to install [libsass](https://github.com/sass/libsass) instead of Ruby Sass, [it is known to compile faster](http://benfrain.com/lightning-fast-sass-compiling-with-libsass-node-sass-and-grunt-sass/).